# How to use `std::lower_bound` with `std::map`?

Tags: c++, stdmap, lower-bound, upperbound

I have this question:

I have a `std::map` of strings to integers representing list of fruits:

```
map<string, int> fruits{
    {"Apple", 5}, {"Grapefruit", 7}, {"Cherry", 10}, {"Grapes", 16}
};


for (const auto& p : fruits)
    cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
cout << endl << endl;


auto it = fruits.begin();
++++it;

using type = std::pair<class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char> > const, int>;

auto it2 = std::lower_bound(fruits.cbegin(), fruits.cend(), type{"Cherry", 10});
//  auto it3 = std::lower_bound(fruits.cbegin(), fruits.cend(), pair<string, int>{ "Cherry", 10 });
auto it4 = std::lower_bound(fruits.cbegin(), fruits.cend(), pair<const string, int>{ "Cherry", 10 });

for (auto beg = fruits.cbegin(); beg != it2; ++beg)
    cout << beg->first << " " << beg->second << endl;

cout << typeid(*it).name() << endl;
```

So my problem was How to pass the third parameter to `std::lower_bound` explicitly?

- Because after getting help from `typeid` I've noticed that the pair's `first` is `const` is this because the keys are `constants`?
- Also what happen if I pass the value for a given key that is not matching the key in the container. e.g: the element with key `"Cherry"` has a value `10` so why `lower_bound` works correctly if I pass to it invalid `value` with the key like `pair{"Cherry", 345}`?
- Is the value of the pair passed to `lower_bound` arbitrary?

Comment: Do you really want to compare both key and value or are you only interested in the key? If its the latter, std::map has a lower_bound member(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound)

Comment: @PhilippLenk: Yes. I get it. is it correct my guess about `const`? Thank you

Comment: It is const because modifying the key's value via iterators or such could potentially break the data structure(as the nodes would have to be reordered). Safely modifying the keys could be done via C++17's extract(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract), which hands you a node removed from the map

Comment: @PhilippLenk: Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do that.  `std::map` has its own member function `lower_bound` so that you don't need a comparison function, and it's more efficient too.

An iterator to `map` has the `first` part `const` because you can't change it.  The data types and algorithms used rely on the key value remaining the same over the life of the map.

Comment: Ah ok. I really tried that. Becuase in my book it is said always use the members of the associative containers (algorithms ) rather than using the generic ones. But add the first part of the questions about constness. Thank you.

Comment: Ok Now Thank you.